# Adding timedelta object to datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timedelta

My timedelta object looks like this: `txdelta = 00:30:00`. I want to add it to a datetime object but it consistently isn't working:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
localdt = datetime.combine(datetime.strptime('2015-06-18', '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
(23:35:02+timedelta(txdelta)).time())
```

Note that the `23:35:02` is already a datetime object. I get this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.timedelta
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update your example so it runs in Python 2.7 as is.  Right now it returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.  Make it return the error you claim.  See [mcve] for guidelines to post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you create your `time` object is strange. I strongly advice you to declare it this way if you're not used to it:

```
txdelta = timedelta(minutes=30)
tdelta = time(hour=1, minute=35, second=2)
```

If I got it well you tried to combine a `date`, a `time` and a `timedelta`. The full code below should do the trick:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

txdelta = timedelta(minutes=30)
tdelta = time(hour=1, minute=35, second=2)
localdt = datetime.combine(datetime.strptime('2015-06-18', '%Y-%m-%d').date(), tdelta) + txdelta

print(localdt)
```

Basically, you combine a datetime object with a time one, and you simply add the timedelta object afterwards.

The output is:

```
2015-06-18 02:05:02
```